# Bazel error: no such package: The repository could not be resolved: Repository is not defined and referenced by

Tags: python, bazel, bazel-rules

I am trying to run a simple python binary with bazel using `bazel run projects/my-python-app/...`. But when I run it I get the error:

```
ERROR: /private/var/tmp/_bazel_justin/84cef48b5ae183d272bc73733d19e8e1/external/python_deps_pypi__flask/BUILD.bazel:11:11: no such package '@python_deps_pypi__itsdangerous//': The repository '@python_deps_pypi__itsdangerous' could not be resolved: Repository '@python_deps_pypi__itsdangerous' is not defined and referenced by '@python_deps_pypi__flask//:pkg'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//projects/my-python-app:main' failed; build aborted:
```

In my `WORKSPACE` I have:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

rules_python_version = "740825b7f74930c62f44af95c9a4c1bd428d2c53" # Latest @ 2021-06-23

http_archive(
    name = "rules_python",
    # Bazel will print the proper value to add here during the first build.
    # sha256 = "FIXME",
    strip_prefix = "rules_python-{}".format(rules_python_version),
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python/archive/{}.zip".format(rules_python_version),
)

load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "pip_parse")

# Create a central repo that knows about the dependencies needed from
# requirements_lock.txt.
pip_parse(
   name = "python_deps",
   requirements_lock = "//third_party:requirements_lock.txt",
)
# Load the starlark macro which will define your dependencies.
load("@python_deps//:requirements.bzl", "install_deps")
# Call it to define repos for your requirements.
install_deps()
```

In my `requirements_lock.txt` I have:

```
Flask==2.0.2
```

In my `BUILD` I have:

```
load("@python_deps//:requirements.bzl", "requirement")

py_binary(
    name = "main",
    srcs = ["main.py"],
    deps = [
        "//projects/calculator:calculator",
        requirement("Flask"),
    ],
)
```

Any ideas what's going on here? I was following the README in https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_python

Answer (score 1):

You can use `compile_pip_requirements` to generate the `requirements_lock.txt` file.

- Add it in the `BUILD` file -

  ```
  load("@rules_python//python:pip.bzl", "compile_pip_requirements")

  compile_pip_requirements(
      name = "requirements",
      requirements_in = "requirements.in",
      requirements_txt = "requirements_lock.txt",
  )
  ```
- Write the base requirements in the `requirements.in`

  ```
  Flask==2.0.2
  ```
- Run the following to generate the lock file

  ```
  bazel run requirements.update
  ```

  Note: initially you need to have the `requirements_lock.txt` file (empty file is okay), otherwise bezel will fail with file not found error

Answer (score -1):

I think you misunderstand the purpose of a requirements_lock.txt, it must contain all the dependencies that are needed to run your python application. I usually create a virtual environment (using pyenv or mkvirtualenv), then I do the installation from a requirements.txt file with just the dependencies that I need (in this case the content of the requirements.txt file must be something like "Flask=2.0.2") and then I generate with "pip freeze > requirements_lock.txt" the requirements_lock.txt

This is an example of the requirements.txt file

```
Flask==2.0.2
```

This is an example of the requirements_lock.txt that you need

```
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.0.2
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.2
Werkzeug==2.3.4
```

If you do so, your bazel run command must success

```
➜  python_example bazel run projects/my-python-app/...
INFO: Analyzed target //projects/my-python-app:main (24 packages loaded, 177 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //projects/my-python-app:main up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/projects/my-python-app/main
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.112s, Critical Path: 0.00s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Running command line: bazel-bin/projects/my-python-app/main
hello
 * Serving Flask app 'main' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on all addresses (0.0.0.0)
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
 * Running on http://192.168.1.17:5000
Press CTRL+C to quit
```

There must be easy ways to generate the requirements_lock.txt, probably from some online website, anyway I hope this give you an idea of the solution

Comment: Daniel's answer is pretty much correct.  You're doing things right; you just need to list dependencies of "Flask" within your requirements_lock.txt

The error:
"...
'@python_deps_pypi__itsdangerous' is not defined and referenced by '@python_deps_pypi__flask
"

Is basically trying to tell you that flask depends on itsdangerous, but itsdangerous is not installed in your central python repo (the python_deps repo defined by pip_parse macro)

You need to include "itsdangerous" and all the other deps of "Flask",
In my case I just went with all the latest versions of all these libraries